# App Store app release with sign-in using only email and password

Tags: ios

I am in the process of creating an ios app, that I want to publish on the app store. Does an ios app require email verification or a 2-step authentication for the normal sign-in/register process compulsorily if I only use email and password ?

Will I need to include Apple sign-in for my app?

I have an app thats ready with a register and login functionality with only email and password. I want to publish the app on appstore.
I am expecting that my app gets published on the app store without any rejections.

Comment: You should refer to clause (v) and (x) in section [5.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage) If you don't use any other social sign in services then you don't need Sign in with Apple,but you may need to convince Apple that user registration is required for your app to function.  You will also need to provide the ability for the user to delete their account in your app